Apache Spark Installation issues
When I was installing Spark, I saw two startup scripts in the sbin directory of Spark. I had a question about this. The names of these two scripts are start-all. sh and start-all-spark. sh, and I was wondering what the difference is between these two scripts? On the Internet, I referred to a Spark installation and configuration tutorial. When it deployed standalone, it used start-all-spark.sh, but when it configured standalone for high availability, that is, when it configured Zookeeper, it used start-all.sh as the startup script. Why is this?
I want to know the difference between the two
